# Probability for an infinite set

Tags: probability, limits, infinity

The way probability is defined as the expected value works for finite sets. The probability of getting heads is out of two possible outcomes, heads or tails. 
If we asked the probability out of an infinite set, like the set of positive integers, we could take a limit. For example, as this [site](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/m/Probability/InfiniteDiscrete.shtml) discusses, if we ask "What is the probability of a random integer being divisible by 5?", we can still answer that question, and the answer if 1/5.

However, if we ask the question of what is the probability that of a random integer *is* 5, and applied the same process, we would get a limit of zero.

Is it possible to ask what is the probability that a random number is 5 in a way that makes sense mathematically?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Not necessarily. It depends what measure you're using.

Comment: Wouldn't that contradict the fact that, however, it is *not* impossible to get a 5? What measure could I define to get a reasonable answer?

Comment: No, because (a) that's not a finite event, and (b) "probability zero" is not the same thing as "impossible" in general.

Comment: Why do you think this doesn't make sense?  Note that the definition of "probability" in this instance is not the same as the definition through a probability space.  There is no way to make the natural numbers into a probability space if each number is to have the same probability.

Comment: For your particular case, [Natural Density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density) is the usual way to deal with it: you can't use normal probability-theory approaches, because there's no uniform distribution on the natural numbers (you could, however, use those approaches on other infinite sets, such as $[0,1]$, which does have a uniform distribution: countability is the trick).

Comment: @user3482749 So, you are saying that my intuition that something that has probability zero means never happening is wrong?

Comment: @user Formally, yes. To borrow a phrase from Douglas Adams, it means that it's "infinitely improbable". For a specific example: if you choose a number uniformly at random from $[0,1]$, the probability of any *particular* number coming up is exactly $0$, but one of them must come up, so one of those (uncountably infinitely many) probability-$0$ events must occur.

Comment: Yes, probability zero does not mean "impossible."  If you pick a real number between $0$ and $1$ uniformly at random, the probability that it is $1/2$ is $0$, but it's obviously possible that you pick $1/2$.

Comment: @user3482749 intuitively, is that the same as saying that, probability zero means never happening, but the limit of probability going to zero means, using your words, infinitely improbable (but not impossible)? (at least for aa countable set)

Comment: @user There's no limit here. The probability is just a number, and that number is $0$. And note that this example only works for uncountable sets: there's no uniform distribution on a countably infinite set.

Comment: Something else: I disagree with what is said on the site with a the link in your question stating in a general sense that the probability of a random integer being divisible by $5$ is $\frac15$. Why should the probability be not e.g. $\frac12$? Think of picking a random number from listing: $1,5,2,10,3,15,4,20,6,25,\cdots$.

Comment: @drhab ok, that is a great comment. are you disagreeing with the result (p=1/5) or just with the process (taking the limit of an increasing set is not well-defined since we are not defining how we pick the increasing sets) or both?

Comment: If no listing is chosen at forehand then the limit is not well defined. If a listing is chosen (e.g. the most natural one:$1,2,3,4,5,6,\dots$) then probabilities can be defined by means of limits. This creates a distribution on a set that contains $5$ elements. This (i.e. finite) makes uniform distribution possible. If it would concern all positive integers then uniform distribution is not possible. Further different listings give different distributions.

Comment: Choosing a random positive integer goes in practice like this: choose a "large" integer $m$ and equip $\{1,2,\dots,m\}$ with uniform distribution. In that context we come to the statement that the probability that a multiple of $5$ will be chosen equals $\frac15$. I have understanding for that, but there is no mathematical justification for taking the set $\{1,2,\dots,m\}$. You could also choose for $\{5,10,15,\dots,m\}$ leading to probability $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to define rather precisely what your random process is for choosing an integer. For example this process allows any non-negative integer to be chosen but gives each one a finite probability:

1. Randomly choose a digit from 0 to 9.
2. Toss a coin. If you get heads, go to step 1.
3. When you finally get tails, string together the chosen digits to make your random integer.

The process is random and obviously able to produce any positive integer or zero, but it's also heavily weighted towards lower numbers. In fact single-digit integers will occur more than half the time (since we might get a string of digits of which all but the last are zero).

Comment: This is a great example, in fact p is greater than zero for any number, but this is okay because it is not the same for every number.

Comment: @user Thanks! Another I thought of was: take a random real number $x\in(0,1)$ then round $\frac1x$ to the nearest integer below. Then there's a $\frac1n$ chance of getting an integer $\geq n$. But I thought getting $1$ half the time was a bit excessive!